# Minecraft PE shows Mojang logo, goes black, and reverts to home screen

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Every time I go into the Minecraft PE app it displays "Mojang", but then it goes black and goes back to the home screen. This only started as soon as I updated to Minecraft PE 0.15.2 on my iPad Mini, and I went to the app and it happened. I did a hard reset, but it still doesn't work. Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Your device probably doesn't meet the requirements.

Which iPad Mini do you have and what version of iOS is it running? Get this info, which you can find in the Settings/General/About and next compare it with the minimum requirements to run the Minecraft PE app on the app store or for more detail here: [Minecraft Gamepedia PE System Requirements](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Pocket_Edition#System_requirements)

If your device doesn't meet the requirements, then don't be surprised if it doesn't work.

Here is a solution to backup your Minecraft PE files and put them back on your iPad once you've uninstalled and reinstalled the app:

> Step 1 : Press the "Recents" button on your device and swipe Minecraft to close it. This will completely close the game and stop it from running in the background.
>
> Step 2 : Download a File Manager app on your device, or connect it to computer. This will allow you to access the file system of your Android device. There are several free file explorers available on the Play Store. ES File Explorer is one of the most popular. If you connect your device via computer, you can navigate through the folders just like you would with Windows folders.
>
> Step 3 : Start the File Manager app on your device. You will see a list of folders on your device. You may have to open the "sdcard" folder to see all of your system folders, depending on your device. You don't need a file manager app if you connect your device to the computer.
>
> Step 4 : Open the games → .com.mojang → minecraftWorlds folder. If you are using your computer, connect your device and select it from the Computer window (Windows) or your desktop (OS X). This will display a list of folders labeled with all of your created worlds, both Creative and Survival.
>
> Step 5 : Open the folder for the Creative world you want to transfer. You should see a "level.dat" file.
>
> Step 6 : Copy the "level.dat" file. Android - Press and hold the "level.dat" file and select "Copy" from the menu that appears. Computer - Right-click on it and select "Copy".
>
> Step 7 : After the backup you go to the same folder and paste your copied files there. If your daughter(s) boots up minecraft again she should have her worlds again.
> NOTE : This only saves the world, the player data might not be saved.

Comment: My ipad mini 2 is running ios the very latest version of ios which is 9.3.2 and my minecraft is latest update and everything should work because it does meet the requirments

Comment: @user153540 Yeah it sounds like it should work fine, did you try to uninstall and reinstall the app?

Comment: I havent tryed that reason being it wont save my worlds but I do have a backup of them in a file on my computer so if it nessesary I will delete reinstall and if it works I will replace the file with my computer, orr do you know if my xbox account will save my worlds and progress?

Comment: If you do have a backup do one, which you will be able to copy back on your iPad Mini afterwards (solution added to my answer). Your minecraft PE and xbox accounts aren't linked last time I checked, so no I don't think your xbox account will save your minecraft PE's progress.

Comment: Ok well I have to go to bed so ill tell you if it works tomorrow thanks for your help

Comment: @user153540 NP, don't forget to validate my answer if it helped you at least your question is marked as solved :)

Comment: Ok thanks for all your help and support you definatly aswered my question and my minecraft pe is working:) It doesnt have my worlds saved but I know exactly how to get them back because I always backup my games folder inside of mcpe and save it on my destop because Im always downloading and creating my own texture packs and puting it in the recource packs folder. All my worlds are saved to whenever I do that because I always save the WHOLE games folder. :) oh and is that validating your answer as solved because it is :)

Comment: @user153540 happy I could help, and to validate the answer you have to click the green tick so that it is green :)